# Ubuntu 14.04 can't shutdown

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 and I cannot shutdown the computer anymore, neither through the top panel, nor by command line.

I tried many solutions suggested online, like updating in `/etc/default/grub` the following line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

I tried with `quiet splash acpi=force`, `quiet splash acpi=off`, `quiet splash reboot=bios`, and even with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`.

I don't have `cairo-dock` installed on my computer, I'm not using proprietary driver but the Xorg nouveau one.

The only solution to quit the computer is by pressing the power button.

This is my actual grub configuration file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that     obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Any other ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: You wrote a lot, but did not mention what your computer is.

Comment: You are right, it is a Gigabyte P34. Shutdown has been working since ever, just from last formatting it does not work anymore, so I don't believe it is related to the particular device! ;)

Comment: What is "last formatting"? What happens if you try to shutdown from CLI, what is `dmesg` output?

Comment: I did format my computer recently. How can I check the `dmesg` after giving the shutdown command?

Comment: And what happens if you run `sudo shutdown -h now`?

Comment: It gets stuck. Terminal disappear but the screen is unresponsive. It doesn't shutdown and I need to long press the power button.

Comment: have you given running `sudo poweroff` from terminal a try?

Comment: It doesn't work. Same problem as `sudo shutdown -h now`! :(